# Does Slick's DBIO.seq method run actions sequentially?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0, slick-2.0

Slick has `DBIO.seq` and `DBIO.sequence` for running many `DBIOAction`s whereby the results of previous actions aren't required for subsequent actions.

I've looked at the source, and it's not obvious to me if `DBIO.seq` runs the actions sequentially. On the other hand, `DBIO.fold` has a very simple implementation which definitely does run the actions sequentially, as it just uses `flatMap` internally.

My question is: will order be guaranteed when using `seq` and `sequence`, like it is with `fold`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/dbio.html#sequential-execution) states that the actions in `DBIO.seq` are run sequentially:

> The simplest combinator is DBIO.seq which takes a varargs list of
>   actions to run in sequence

Also, in the [source code](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/0358386eed2be1f369d829e081a4dec5e66825a5/slick/src/main/scala/slick/dbio/DBIOAction.scala#L229) for `DBIO.seq`, you will see that `SynchronousDatabaseAction` is called inside `foreach`, which means that each are sequantially and (internally) synchronously called without any parallel run.